# Is it possible that Socket.BeginConnect throws an exception after the asynccallback is called?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible that [Socket.BeginConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tad07yt6.aspx) throws an exception after the asynccallback is called?

```
socket.BeginConnect(remoteEP, callback, state);
```

In this case, could it be that callback is executed, but the caller of socket.BeginConnect still receives a SocketException?

Answer (score 0):

No. A Google of "MSDN Socket.BeginConnect" yields [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tad07yt6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which *clearly* defines what exceptions can be thrown from this method, and under what conditions.

If an exception is thrown, the callback will not occur. If the callback occurs, therefore, an exception was not thrown by `BeginConnect`. The callback may receive an exception on its end, however, when you call `EndConnect`.

Comment: @BenStrombeck I derped at reading comprehension. I thought he was asking if it could throw an exception *at all*. ;)